# The Jackson API and stack traces for infine recursion

Tags: json, jackson, stack-trace

I've noticed that the jackson API obfuscates an infinite recursion by wrapping, and displaying a "chain" that hints at the recursion, i.e. something along the lines of this:

```
ArrayList[0]->"fieldX"->"..".
```

I'm wondering what the advantage of doing this is?  I recently had alot of trouble with an infinite recursion bug which would be quite easy to trace if the explicit calls were made available.

I suspect it has to do with the fact that, maybe jackson's introspection of the methods is happening in a separate thread, or is done in a way that loses the explicit stack calls.

Comment: Are you sure Jackson just isn't *itself* throwing that "nice" error message when it (*itself*) detects such a cyclic condition? When traversing object graphs it is common to remember where you've been ..

Comment: maybe... if so im dissapointed because, even if there was a cycle in my code... it would be easier to let the JRE stacktrace it for me then rely on a high level preemptive exception message sent before the error occured.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson does indeed catch this, since more often than not displaying data structure that causes it is much more useful than raw stack trace. Raw stack trace can show you where things happen, but oftentimes not why they happen.

However: one thing Jackson probably should do is to chain the original exception as root cause, to also allow you to inspect it. Looks like this is not yet done, but it should be very easy to add.

I will go ahead and file RFE for this.